# adding an after_create method in Rails Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin, after-create

I'm using Rails 4.1 and Rails Admin. I have a Project Model with the following fields:
name:
slug:
project_number.

When I create a new project in the admin I want the project_number to be created automatically using the id and the slug. Like this:
`self.project_number = self.slug + '_' + self.id`

I was trying to do this in the project controller using an after_create method, I'm now realising that rails_admin is not hitting my controller.
Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do this? Would this be a rails_admin custom action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you need grab `after_create` in the model.

/models/project.rb

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_create :generate_project_number


  def generate_project_number
    self.project_number = "#{slug}_#{id}"
  end

end
```

In this way when you create a new Project (form anywhere) `project_number` will be saved as "slug_id"

```
[29] pry(main)> Project.create!(slug: 'hello_world')
=> #<Project id: 3, slug: "hello_world", project_number: "hello_world_3", created_at: "2016-05-11 23:00:19", updated_at: "2016-05-11 23:00:19">
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the answer I needed, it works!